# Hover effect with anchor tag on image not working

Tags: html, css, hover

I want [this effect](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWjpzL) for my image.

I implemented it but I have anchor at the place of figure and when I hover on image I should able to click on it and it should redirect. Will we achieve it?

I use the following code for the hover effect:

```
.tint {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 3px 5px 5px;
}

.tint:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.tint:hover:before { background: rgba(0,0,255, 0.5); }
```

If I remove `position:absolute`, the link starts working but then the hover effect is gone.

Please help me with this if anybody has any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something by the meanings of this code:

```
<div>
<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
<div class="mask">
</div>
</div>


<style>
    .mask {  position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      transition: all 0.6s ease;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background-color: #0af;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .mask:hover {
      background-color: #0af;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: brief explanation: you set a div with your image, then a mask that is absolute positioned right after, and make so that whenever you hover it, it becomes visible (opacity > 0)